# location for make available offline settings

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Where in a Windows XP system are the settings for a folder that is set to be available offline?  I have located the specific settings for the 'My Documents' Folder, however I cannot find anything about other arbitrary locations one might choose.

Comment: Sounds more like a SuperUser question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about, a shared network location...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307853

..that should help. If not, could you explain more what you are trying to do?

Cheers

Comment: No i know how to use them, im trying to figure out where the information is stored for the path.  IE how does windows know that path \\foo\bar\baz is available offline and where does it store that information.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not really make sense with regards to "My Documents" and "arbitrary locations".

1. If you are talking about Offline Files, they are enabled by opening "My Computer" and going to Tools>Folder Options>Offline Files.
2. From there, they are stored in the %windir%\CSC hidden folder.
3. Change the location of the CSC files (if you have more space on another drive, for example) using cachemov.exe for XP/server 2003 or in accordance with the following article for Vista/Windows 7.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937475

Comment: Yes i know how to enable them, and im not particularly concerned with where the actual cached files are stored.  Im intersted in where windows stores the location those files are cached *from*.  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders "Personal" is the explicitly defined registry entry for 'My Documents'.  What key (if any) represents some other arbitrary location, say \\foo\bar\baz\?

Comment: The cached copies are stored in the CSC directory...that location information is also stored there in the namespace directory.